# How to assign row number using row_number() to a repeated values in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have some rows in data where agentid and customer ids are being repeated. like so
[image: table 1]

I want to assign a row number to each of the repeated value so that the result looks like this table below: Table 2:

| agentid | customerid | row_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 26 | 1234 | 1 |
| 26 | 1234 | 2 |
| 26 | 1234 | 3 |
| 26 | 1234 | 4 |
| 26 | 1454 | 1 |
| 26 | 1256 | 1 |
| 26 | 1256 | 2 |
| 30 | 1256 | 1 |

I am new to PostgreSQL, so I tried this:

```
select agentid, customerid, row_number() OVER () from aa_dev.calls group by agentid, customerid having count(customerid) > 1;
```

This query above selected all the repeated pairs and assigned rows to each of them
[image: table 3]

but I want to create something that I mentioned above in table 2.
Please guide me about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY agentid, customerid ORDER BY random()) rn,
              COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY agentid, customerid) cnt
    FROM aa_dev.calls
)

SELECT agentid, customerid, rn      
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1;
```